# Parsing IMAP responses in python

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I am using imaplib to work with imap in python, however it looks like it doesn't have means to parse the details of IMAP responses. For example, query like:

```
   msgdata = connection.fetch(num, "(BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO CC DATE SUBJECT MESSAGE-ID)] UID)")
```

where `num` is the message number, for one mail server may produce (for example):

```
  ('OK', [('1234 (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO CC DATE SUBJECT MESSAGE-ID)] {123}', 'From: ...etc headers'), ' UID 3456)'])
```

and for another:

```
  ('OK', [('1234 (UID 3456 BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO CC DATE SUBJECT MESSAGE-ID)] {123}', 'From: ...etc headers'), ')'])
```

As you see, the message details are different and UID is even in different element there. So the question is - is there some library that would allow to automatically sort it out and abstract the details of what particular mail server does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doug Hellman's [Python Module of the Week entry for imaplib](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/imaplib/) is a fairly extensive tutorial on the subject, but is far to long to reproduce here.

You might want to use a higher level library like [IMAPClient](http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/) to hide some of the details of the IMAP protocol.

Comment: Unfortunately, Doug's tutorial kind of glides over the topic of parsing more complex fetch() responses. Thanks for the link to IMAPClient, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 3):

High level IMAP lib may be useful: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

```
from imap_tools import MailBox
# get list of email subjects from INBOX folder
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'password', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    data = [(msg.uid, msg.subject) for msg in mailbox.fetch()]
```

Comment: this library appears to have the most dev activity of the 3, 2022-03

Answer (score 1):

Look at Imbox, you will probably find what your are looking for https://pypi.org/project/imbox/

Comment: this appears to have the most stars on github, 1.1k as of 2022-03